# Android : Text View Linkify.add link makes complete line in text view clickable

Tags: android, hyperlink, linkify

I am showing some text in a text view which is an element inside list view. I am using Linkify.addLinks to add links in the textview. But the problem is that the complete line containing the links becomes clickable instead of just the text(words) which I intend to linkify.

My function :

```
private static void linkifyPattern(TextView view, String text, String url) {

    Linkify.TransformFilter filter = new Linkify.TransformFilter() {
        @Override
        public String transformUrl(Matcher match, String url) {
            return url;
        }
    };
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(text);
    Linkify.addLinks(view, pattern, null, null, filter);
}
```

and the custom text view I am using contains :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    TextView widget = (TextView) this;
    Object text = widget.getText();
    if (text instanceof Spanned) {
        Spannable buffer = (Spannable) text;

        int action = event.getAction();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            x -= widget.getTotalPaddingLeft();
            y -= widget.getTotalPaddingTop();

            x += widget.getScrollX();
            y += widget.getScrollY();

            Layout layout = widget.getLayout();
            int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
            int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

            ClickableSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(off, off,
                    ClickableSpan.class);

            if (link.length != 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < link.length;) {
                    System.out.println("Link:: " + link[i].toString());
                    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        link[i].onClick(widget);
                    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Selection.setSelection(buffer,
                                buffer.getSpanStart(link[i]),
                                buffer.getSpanEnd(link[i]));
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

And the xml code for the text view is :

```
 <com.presenter.custom.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/news_message_collapsed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/news_view_text_right_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorLink="@color/red"
            android:textSize="@dimen/news_view_text_size" />
```

Thank you